# Populate table with variable created from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a table that is populated with data that I then need to use to run a second query.  I am using jquery datatables and those are the functions that you see that allow me to grab all the content from the table.  So for example I am grabbing an integer out of the fourth column like this and then using that number to run a query for a json response :

```
var cells = [];
var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
for( var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        {
            var grabsku = $j(rows[i]).find('td:eq(3)').text();
            grabsku = grabsku.substring(0, 6) + "-0" + grabsku.substring(7, grabsku.length - 4);
            s7url = 'http://jsonquery.com/' + grabsku  + '?req=exists,json';        

      $j.ajax({
        url: s7url,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
       }
```

THen with that ajax request the json returns either a 1 or 0 which I can then form the correct info depending on what is returned.

```
function s7jsonResponse(response)
        {
        var s7img = sku;
        s7img = '<img src="http://imageserver.com/is/image/' + s7img.substring(0, 6) + "-0" + s7img.substring(7, s7img.length - 4) + '">';
         x = response["catalogRecord.exists"];  
             z = x == "0" ? "NO IMG" : s7img;
             console.log(z);
        }
```

Console now shows me what I want for z variable, either an image path or NO IMG.  My problem is getting this out of console and actually back into the table.  What I want to happen is as each response comes in to replace a td in the table with the z variable.  I tried to put this in the jsonResponse but it did not work correctly.  How could I iterate through the table, in this case `(td:eq(2))` and replace each cell with the variable `z` I get back from this query?

Comment: fnGetNodes(0 is very limited..read disclaimer http://datatables.net/ref. You will need to track the row index in your ajax response (send it to server and get server to return it likely easiest) and use fnUpdate() to target row and cell

Comment: thanks for the idea.. not sure how i could pass info through this response as you suggest

Comment: when you send data to server, send the row index as well, send json back from server with row index and your new data  and plug them both into fnUpdate

Comment: hmm ok I will look into it.  I dont control the server I am sending the data too.. does that matter?

Comment: seems like you should be able to do these lookups on server and store the data once instead of many json requests every time page loads...just a thought

Comment: yes that would be nice to prevent these requests but the data is always changing and seems like a lot of work to run checks for what is new (least I am not sure how to do it).  This script is for an internal tool that would only be used every day or two.  Thanks for the answer below, I will be giving it a go here soon.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a function to do the ajax that you can pass the row index and the url that contains data query string to as arguments. Since you know the cell index , once data returned from ajax you can call `fnUpdate` for using new data and row index within success of the ajax

```
var cells = [];
var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var grabsku = $j(rows[i]).find('td:eq(3)').text();
    grabsku = grabsku.substring(0, 6) + "-0" + grabsku.substring(7, grabsku.length - 4);
    s7url = 'http://jsonquery.com/' + grabsku + '?req=exists,json';
    var rowIndex = i;
    doAjax(s7url, rowIndex)
}



function doAjax(url, rowIndex) {
    $j.ajax({
        url: s7url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(repsonse) {

            var s7img = sku;
            s7img = '<img src="http://imageserver.com/is/image/' + s7img.substring(0, 6) + "-0" + s7img.substring(7, s7img.length - 4) + '">';
            x = response["catalogRecord.exists"];
            z = x == "0" ? "NO IMG" : s7img;
            console.log(z);
        /* do fnUpdate here using new data and rowIndex and you know the cell index already*/
        }



    });
}
```